# Making sense of 'doch'

Tags: meaning-in-context

What is the purpose served by 'doch' in the 2 sentences below:

1. Meine Mutter macht eigentlich komplett alles. Das ist **doch** verdammt schön.

Thank you.

2. Ich will, dass meine Kinder selbständig werden. **Doch** der Verstand sagt so, und das Herz sagt etwas Anderes. Das Herz sagt, ich finde es schön, wenn sie da sind.

Comment: I assume, you've already looked up the _doch_ and tried to translate the sentences? Could you please edit your question and add, what exactly remains unclear? Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

In the first case it's a filler word that enhances the weight of the sentence. If you were to translate it, it would probably mean something like "actually" or "after all" ("It is like that, even though you might think otherwise").

In the second case it is a shortened form of "Jedoch" replacing "Aber" meaning "but" / "nevertheless" (maybe with a hint of "alas" in this case).

Comment: For use-case 1 you could also say: it expresses the speaker's emotional involvement.